# Pointer to array structure

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have a small program which when compiling throws me the following errors

> error #2168: Operands of '+' have incompatible types 'struct agenda' and 'int'.
>
> error #2113: Left operand of '.' has incompatible type 'int'.
>
> error #2088: Lvalue required.

This is the code that I have done

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct agenda{
    int order, cellular;
    char name[30], last_name[30], street[30], city[30], mail[50];
}contact[10];

int main(void)
{
    struct agenda *ptrcontact;
    ptrcontact = &contact[0];

    (*ptrcontact+3).order = 3;

    printf("\n\n %d", (*ptrcontact).order);
    return 0;
}
```

because it throws these errors and how to fix them?

Comment: what is `*ptrcontact`? Its `contact[0]`. You should try something like: `(ptrcontact + 3)->order = 3;`

Comment: (*ptrcontact+3) gives you whatever ptrcontact points at (a struct agenda) and adds 3 (int) to that. * has higher precedence than +, so in order to get the third index, you have to either write: *(ptrcontact + 3) or ptrcontact[3].

Answer (score 6):

You need to change

```
(*ptrcontact+3).order = 3;
```

to

```
ptrcontact[3].order = 3;
```

or, at least,

```
(*(ptrcontact+3)).order = 3;
```

or,

```
(ptrcontact + 3)->order = 3;
```

Otherwise, as per the [precedence rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), `*` has higher precedence over `+`, causing the error.

Just to add to that, `ptrcontact` is a pointer ( to `struct agenda`) and can be used as an operand to `+` operator.

OTOH, `*ptrcontact` is of type `struct agenda` and cannot be used as an operand to `+` operator.

Answer (score 2):

You are dereferencing the pointer which yields the struct and obviously you can't add anything to that. Dereference operator has the highest priority, you need to do it like this: `(*(ptr + 3)).order` or use the arrow instead of star dot: `(ptr + 3) -> order`

Comment: Man that really took me this long to type up

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is operations priority:

```
 (*ptrcontact+3).order = 3;
```

This derefers `ptrcontract` and then tries to add number to dereferred structure. Which gives you exact situation you report.

My recommendations:

Either avoid address ariphmetics in such cases. Operate array indexes.

```
int baseIndex = 0;
contact[baseIndex + 3].order = 3;
```

Or if you really have to do so, hide address arithmetic from outside:

```
(pcontact + 3)->order = 3;
```

And finally learn [C language operations priority](http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html) or, to do it once (but some C people don't like C++), [C++ operations priority](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: This is a c question and the provided link will contain operators that are not even valid in the c language. `en.cppreference.com` is a c++ resource, not a c resource.

Comment: Exactly. But all valid operations priorities are as C programmer expects ;-). This is just to not learn them again when C++ starts.

Comment: I don't think every c programmer has to learn such an ugly language.

Comment: :-))) I agree with you somewhat. I've migrated to Java then Scala after C++11. Actually C++ is now too complex and too broad for single language - this results 'several languages in one'. But reality is - C programmers often learn C++ and (which makes the deal) then they return to C and become real programmers - after this they start to be language-agnostic. :-|

Comment: OK, I agreed C priorities at least should be referred first.

Answer (score 0):

the error is in the lines
(*ptrcontact+3).order = 3; and printf("\n\n %d", (*ptrcontact).order);. In this instructions use -> instead of . the errors will be solved.